# Deploying Golang app on Docker exits process

Tags: docker, go

I'm very new to Docker. I have a Golang app that has the following structure:

```
.
├── 404.html
├── Dockerfile
├── index.html
├── scripts
├── server.go
├── static
│   ├── jquery.min.js
│   ├── main.css
│   └── main.js
└── styles
```

I got the Dockerfile from DockerHub. It's too large to post here, but the [full version is here](https://github.com/docker-library/golang/blob/fa0223eaa427188e0c70025f557d515129a9973f/1.10/alpine3.7/Dockerfile). The last few lines of the Dockerfile, which I think might be relevant, are:

```
ENV GOPATH /go
ENV PATH $GOPATH/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH

RUN mkdir -p "$GOPATH/src" "$GOPATH/bin" && chmod -R 777 "$GOPATH"
WORKDIR $GOPATH
```

When I go into my directory and type in `docker build -t my-app .` then it successfully builds. When I type in `docker run -d -p 80:80 url-shortener`, it gives me a string which I assume is the ID.

But when I do `docker ps`, it doesn't show the process running.
If I do `docker ps -a`, it shows the process but it says,

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
6adc34244350        my-app       "/bin/sh"           6 minutes ago 
Exited (0) 6 minutes ago
```

I apologize if this is a very dumb question. I'm a complete Docker noob and could use some guidance.

Comment: I dont see launch command, how you run your program?

Answer (score 2):

From your `docker ps` output, your image is configured to only run a shell.  Since you ran it as a background process without any input, it processed all of its input and exited successfully (status code 0).  `docker logs 6adc34244350` will show you what output (if any) it produced.

Docker has an excellent [tutorial on writing and running custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) that's worth reading.  In particular, you shouldn't copy the official `golang` Dockerfile; your own Dockerfile can start with `FROM golang:1.10` and it will inherit everything in that image.  You also almost certainly want to make sure you have a `CMD` command that runs your application (by default) when the container starts up.